# Text editor to test TTF fonts in Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts

I have hundred of TTF font files and I just want to test them without having to install. Is there any text editor in Windows that allows to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know such editor, but you can try some of these utilities:
http://www.portablefreeware.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1162

at least some of them can view fonts which are not installed and use custom text to compare them. I have also some older util for this, but I am not able to remember its name now.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have also tried a lot of softwares to see but most of them are really old and out of date and doesn't support Unicode characters.